# Are there multiple Jabberwockies in Once Upon a Time in Wonderland?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

In season 2 episode 13 of Once Upon a Time, a woman named Jack (of Jack and the Beanstalk) says in Tiny the giant's flashback that she was awarded a mushroom because she once slayed a Jabberwocky.  Yet in Season 1 Episode 9 of "Once Upon a Time in Wonderland" (last night's midseason premiere), Jafar unleashes a woman who says "They call me the Jabberwocky."  How is this possible?  Once Upon a Time in Wonderland takes place during Season 2 of Once Upon a Time, which is during the time when the fairytale characters are in Storybrooke.  So this is after Jack slayed a Jabberwocky.

So are there multiple Jabberwockies?  That seems inconsistent with the woman in last night's episode saying "They call me the Jabberwocky", implying that it's a monicker given to a single individual.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

EDIT: Here is what Jack says: "Magic. A piece of mushroom from a far-off land. I once slayed a Jabberwock that was terrorizing a village, and they—they couldn't pay me in gold, so they paid me with this instead. If you eat it, it will change your size."

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jack was lying. Not sure though.

Comment: @MiharuDante I know Jack lied about being Tiny's friend, but why would she lie about this?  I'm inclined to believe her, because where else would she get a mushroom that changes your size?  That's a hallmark of Wonderland.

Comment: I am positively sure that she was lying because it is almost impossible to cross between realms unless with the Mad Hatters hat or your a Rumplestiltskin.

Comment: @MiharuDante But the mushroom was a clear sign of Wonderland.  I think Jack may have gone through the looking glass or through the rabbit's hole or something.

Comment: What's your evidence for this statement? "Once Upon a Time in Wonderland takes place during Season 2 of Once Upon a Time"

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The first episode of Once Upon a Time in Wonderland shows the Knave of Hearts in Storybrooke, breaking into Granny's while Ella and Leroy take cover from the storm created due to the wraith, as seen in Season 2 Episode 1 of Once Upon a time.  And creator Adam Horowitz has confirmed this in response to Twitter questions.

Answer (score 4):

Jack said that she slayed "a jabberwock". This could mean that a jabberwock and the Jabberwocky are not the same thing. In Carroll's poem, the jabberwock is the name of the creature while Jabberwocky is the poem's title. Maybe she's like the queen bee among jabberwocks? It would explain why she's so powerful, yet Jack could apparently slay a jabberwock by herself.

Or maybe she's just called the Jabberwocky like Elizabeth is called Lizard, or Rumplestiltskin is called Crocodile.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely to be true answer is that Jack THOUGHT she slayed the Jabberwock, but really didn't. We see in most of that episode that she is good with a sword, but the only thing that can harm/kill the Jabberwocky is the pirate-looking sword that pinned her to the wall/roof. Don't you think that if she knew/thought It was dead, wouldn't she have taken the sword for herself, because if that was powerful enough to hurt the Jabberwocky, then it must be incredibly powerful (as far as we know).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind also that Jack may have killed the jabberwock in the world where the enchanted forest lies. She doesn't specify where she was at the time. This is a different world than Wonderland because a portal has to be conjured to travel between the two world, through the mad hatters hat, the looking glass or the rabbit hole. So its definitely possible for there to be two different jabberwockys in two different worlds. OUAT always ties the stories together just give them time. They still have to explain why there are 2 red queens.

Comment: @Well, I think Jack probably went to Wonderland, because why else would she get the mushroom that changes your size as her reward?  That's a hallmark of Wonderland.

Comment: And what do you mean by two Red Queens?  The Queen of Hearts and the Red Queen are completely different.

Comment: Here's what Jack says: "Magic. A piece of mushroom from a far-off land. I once slayed a Jabberwock that was terrorizing a village, and they—they couldn't pay me in gold, so they paid me with this instead. If you eat it, it will change your size. "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe she THOUGHT she killed the Jabberwock, pinning it to the wall with a giant knife and saving everyone... not knowing Jaffar would someday release it.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility.  Maybe the Jabberwock pretended she was dead.